# Passing filters(functions) to custom ansible filter plugin

Tags: ansible

I'd like to pass functions(such as `contains`, `defined`, [etc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)) to my ansible-filter plugin. In a same manner that is passed to [map()](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) for example.

e.g:

```
# playbook

    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ my_dict | my_filter('contains', 'somevalue') }}"

# plugin    

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
      return {'my_filter': self.my_filter}

    def my_filter(data, function):
      something = function(data)
      return something
```

However, In official [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) and [across the internet](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2019-04-25-writing-ansible-filter-plugins/) I only found examples of how to pass data but not callables.